# Pass object from asp-c# to jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

i want to pass an object from c# to jquery but it didn't work. Here is my code
c#:

```
public class ImgLink
{
    public string img;
}

[WebService(Namespace = "")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class ImgService : WebService
{
    List<ImgLink> Imgs = new List<ImgLink>{
        new ImgLink{img="/kazvan-1.jpg"},
        new ImgLink{img="/kazvan-2.jpg"},
        new ImgLink{img="/wojno-3.jpg"}
    };
    [WebMethod]
    public List<ImgLink> GetAllImgs()
    {
        return Imgs;
    }
}
```

### Script:

```
function getImgs() {
     var myArray = [];
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "ImgService/GetAllImgs",
         data: "{}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (response) {
             var cars = response.d;
             $.each(cars, function (index, car) {
                 myArray.push({ "image": +car.img });
             });
             alert("success");
         },
         failure: function (msg) {
             alert("fail");
         }
    });
    return myArray;
}
```

my result: MyArray has nothing.

expected result:

```
myArray = [{ image: '/kazvan-1.jpg' },{ image: '/kazvan-2.jpg' },{ image: '/wojno-3.jpg' }]
```

Comment: You said your expected result, but what is your ACTUAL result? If the url *Really* ImgService  or is it ImgService.asmx?

Comment: Your best bet is to return a JsonResult of your object from the function, then you will have the object available in Javascript.

Comment: Well, this line: myArray.push({ "image": +car.img }); is wrong. it should just be: myArray.push({ "image": car.img }); Does that help? I ran your code and it worked fine (except the +car.img part. Even then I still had an array with 3 items)

Comment: Look in Fiddler or Chrome developer tools Network tab or your favorite tool for network traffic and see what the response being returned is. You might also want to look at Dave Ward's article about ASP.NET's ".d", http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/. What I usually do is the following var cars = response.d || response

Comment: You are not responding to any of the answers or comments. please respond. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class ImgLink
{
    public string img;
}


    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
     [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class ImgService : WebService
{
    List<ImgLink> Imgs = new List<ImgLink>{
        new ImgLink{img="/kazvan-1.jpg"},
        new ImgLink{img="/kazvan-2.jpg"},
        new ImgLink{img="/wojno-3.jpg"}
    };
    [WebMethod]
    public List<ImgLink> GetAllImgs()
    {
        return Imgs;
    }
}
```

and jQuery:

```
function getImgs() {
     var myArray = [];
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "ImgService/GetAllImgs",
         data: "{}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (response) {
             var cars = response.d;
             $.map(cars, function (item) {//use .map method
                 myArray.push({ "image": +item.img });
             });
             alert("success");
         },
         failure: function (msg) {
             alert("fail");
         }
    });
    return myArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify in your service that you want to return `JSON`, like this:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

Omitting that returns `XML` instead.